# Nested processes with Dask and Machine learning models

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-ml

I have a dataset consisting of 100000 samples.

I need to split this dataset into 100 subsets and for each subset train a ML model.
Since the trained models are independent, it's easy to parallelize this part doing something like

```
from dask import compute, delayed
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

X, y = load_data()
n_windows = 100
model = Lasso()

results = []
for i in range(0, len(X), n_windows):
    results.append(delayed(model.fit)(X, y))
    
results = compute(results)
```

But say the model itself needs to spawn processes for example if the model is a pipeline which contains a cross validation like `GridSearchCV` or `HyperBandSearchCV`.

How does it work then?
How should I parallelize this code?
It's not clear to me how to make it work, especially if I use `sklearn` estimators like `GridSearchCV` or `ColumnTransformer` which use `joblib` instead of `dask` to parallelize computations.

In fact, depending on whether I use a `Client` or not like so:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

and depending of whether this instantiated `client` is created in the main script or imported from a different module I get either a warning or an error.

In the first case the code is successfully executed but I get a warning saying:

`Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nested, setting n_jobs=1`

In the second case the code is never finished, the interpreter stack and I get this error:

`daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`

Any help how to tackle this problem would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Dask ML](https://ml.dask.org/), it has much of what you need.

- [GridSearchCV](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV)
- [HyperBandSearchCV](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.HyperbandSearchCV.html#dask_ml.model_selection.HyperbandSearchCV)
- [ColumnTransformer](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generted/dask_ml.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#dask_ml.compose.ColumnTransformer)
- [Linear Models](https://ml.dask.org/glm.html)